# jQuery - Fancybox with iframe

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I'm using Fancybox with iframes to load PDF files from database in it. The main idea is that on normal page I have table with content and every row contains field "show invoice", example:

### No     | Title      |   PDF file    |  Action

### 1.    | invoice 1  |   show inovice|  edit

### 2.    | invoice 2  |   show inovice|  edit

3. | invoice 3  |   show inovice|  edit

Now, let say that "show invoice" are links:

...
...

So, clicking on link I'll end up on page where my PDF file(s) will be loaded, but I wanted to have those PDF files in FancyBox with arrows left and right. 
I managed to connect everything ok, but I can't force FancyBox to show arrows left and right, so that I would be able to show other PDF files, one after another.

Any idea, suggestions or so?

And, this is the way I call fancybox (of course, I linked jQuery and funcybox on the top):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".iframe").fancybox({

    'transitionOut' :'elastic',
    'speedIn'  :600, 
    'speedOut'  :200, 
    'width'  :1020,
    'height'  :1000,
    'titleShow'  :false,
    'hideOnOverlayClick':false,
    'hideOnContentClick':false
 });
});
```

Comment: Frejm mora da ti bude manji od fensiBoxa, da li je? / Your `IFRAME` must be smaller then `fancybox`, is it?

Answer (score 1):

Fancybox doesn't care what method it's using, just make sure you place the same `rel` attribute on all of your links that you want in the same gallery (i.e. `rel="pdfGallery"`, `rel="imgGallery"`).

On a side note... If you're using `?iframe` in your links to trigger the iframe type of fancybox, remove that and add `'type':'iframe'` as the last option in your fancybox settings.  It will make your javascript more efficient.